# PowerBI: Two Python instances run the same script backend on Apply or Run

Tags: python, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

When I apply or run the PowerBI Python script, I see two of the following:

- Two Python instances executing the same script

[image: Task Manager]

- Both codes utilizes all resources similarly
- Both generate their own log files

This is redundant, takes double the time, uses all my resources, and is super annoying!

Why is this the case? Can we avoid this or fix this somehow so that only one instance of python executes the script to generate data for the data source?

Comment: Python Power Query step or Python Visual?  If Power Query step, are you referencing that query in another query too?

Comment: Power Query. Only one power query with Python script.